# What is the difference between method handlers such .get, .post and actions such as .list, .create

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am learning Django Rest Framework and one of the things I have noticed is that Viewsets provide actions such as .list, .post instead of method handlers such as .get, .post which in turn are provided by Views. The documentation says that actions are more flexible than method handlers but I can't seem to find any reason for this. Could you please share some information on why does Viewsets use actions and not the method handlers?​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request handlers like .get() and .post() are based on http request methods, while actions like .create() or .list() are from a functionality point of view. Suppose you have a view class that can return a single user's info by user id or return all users in sorted order. These two requests are all GET requests from the client side, but with different parameters and purposes. If you just want to use .get() handler in this case you will need to define two view functions and register the two urls in url config. Or you can use ViewSet class or generic view with mixins that has action functions .list() and .retrieve() to handle these requests, then using router class to set the url configs that follows the REST url standards.

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST are the only HTTP methods to use when dealing with forms.

Django’s login form is returned using the POST method, in which the browser bundles up the form data, encodes it for transmission, sends it to the server, and then receives back its response.

GET, by contrast, bundles the submitted data into a string, and uses this to compose a URL. The URL contains the address where the data must be sent, as well as the data keys and values. You can see this in action if you do a search in the Django documentation, which will produce a URL of the form https://docs.djangoproject.com/search/?q=forms&release=1.

GET and POST are typically used for different purposes.

Any request that could be used to change the state of the system - for example, a request that makes changes in the database - should use POST. GET should be used only for requests that do not affect the state of the system.

GET would also be unsuitable for a password form, because the password would appear in the URL, and thus, also in browser history and server logs, all in plain text. Neither would it be suitable for large quantities of data, or for binary data, such as an image. A Web application that uses GET requests for admin forms is a security risk: it can be easy for an attacker to mimic a form’s request to gain access to sensitive parts of the system. POST, coupled with other protections like Django’s CSRF protection offers more control over access.

On the other hand, GET is suitable for things like a web search form, because the URLs that represent a GET request can easily be bookmarked, shared, or resubmitted.